# lea in assembly x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I am stuck in a cs homework trying to understand lea command in assembly. I understand when I see lea (a,b,i), c this means c = a + b*i. But when I see things like lea 0x3(%rdx), ecx i get confused. Is this just ecx = rdx + 3? Also in the assignment they used rax and eax together. What does this mean. I will post the question below for reference but I am NOT looking for the solution, just some guidance please. [image: question]

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And yes, you can mix rax and eax like that. It means exactly what you think it does. `eax = 5 + rdx + rax * 1`. The reason it's used is that it is 1 byte shorter in machine code than `lea 5(%edx, %eax, 1), %eax` as it doesn't need a 32 bit override prefix.

Comment: thanks @Jester. But can u explain what is going on in lines 6 and 7

Comment: Not sure what explanation you need, especially since you did not want the solution :) I have written what line 6 does and you have described line 7 yourself. It's just an arbitrary formula to calculate a return value.

Comment: haha yes. but what i got is val+= i+5; val *= i+3; for the loop body and i < val for the condition. but this is an infinite loop and somethings wrong here. @Jester

Comment: Looks okay to me. The loop condition uses `edi` which is your `x` though.